# How to implement progress bar while doing stuff?

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress, android-progressbar

i need to set a circular progress bar while doing some stuff.
I've already done this:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

in my `OnCreate()` and then called `progressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible)` and `View.Gone` after doing things, but the progressBar is not displaying.

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 thumbnailAux = doThings(thumbnail);
 image.setImageBitmap(thumbnailAux);
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The method doThings takes a few seconds to complete execute.
Please help!!

Comment: This will not work, you need to use a background thread and post User Interface updates regularly on the main thread. Take a look at AsyncTask in the documentation.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: better to used Progress Dialog in  AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

Android has a Predefined class for a progress bar, its in a class called ProgressDialog. It looks like this:

[image]

You can add this codes in your onCreate() and set the state of the progressDialog like this:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

Also add this following code to a background Thread.

```
private class ProgressThread extends Thread {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    public ProgressThread(Context context, ProgressDialog progress) {
        progress.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        // update progressbar here
    }
}
```

For more details you can check the Android API Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

This [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progressbar.htm) has a full application demo about it, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply AsyncTask for this case.

You can refer more information from this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You can add progressDialog to onPreExecute method and then dismiss in onPostExecute method.

```
// Async Task to access the web
    private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog myPd_bar;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myPd_bar=new ProgressDialog(class.this);
            myPd_bar.setMessage("Loading....");
            myPd_bar.setTitle(Title);
            myPd_bar.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

             //Things should do in, until progress bar close
             return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            myPd_bar.dismiss();
        }
    }// end async task
```